# Why is firebase user token changing?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-authentication

When a user signs up with firebase in my android app, a FirebaseUser object is generated and from this I retrieve the user token to save as a unique identifier for each user in my google cloud endpoints backend.

I use an auth state listener which is called when the user signs up:

```
mAuthListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
            FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
            if (user != null) {
                mUserId = user.getToken(true).toString();
                SignUpAboutFragment signUpAboutFragment = new SignUpAboutFragment();
                FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                ft.replace(R.id.sign_up_fragment_container, signUpAboutFragment, SIGN_UP_ABOUT_FRAGMENT_TAG);
                ft.addToBackStack(null);
                ft.commit();
            }
        }
};
```

The field mUserId is then used to save the profile into the google datastore:

```
mPresenter.saveUserData(firstName, lastName, birthday, mUserId, this, MainActivity.class);
```

In a different activity I also wish to use the current users token to make calls to my endpoint api:

```
//Different activity to the above.
FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
if (user != null) {
    // Using getToken as recommended in the firebase docs.
    mUserId = user.getToken(true).toString();
}
```

When I log both mUserId fields in the 2 activities I find that they are different.

Why is mUserId changing and how do I retrieve the **same** token of the current user from anywhere in my app?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tokens are actually a unique id to identify user connection. So everytime a connection is restarted, another token is generated. If you want to use a unique identifier for each user, you should get its uid. Like this:

```
mAuthListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
            FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
            if (user != null) {
                mUserId = user.getUid();
                SignUpAboutFragment signUpAboutFragment = new SignUpAboutFragment();
                FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                ft.replace(R.id.sign_up_fragment_container, signUpAboutFragment, SIGN_UP_ABOUT_FRAGMENT_TAG);
                ft.addToBackStack(null);
                ft.commit();
            }
        }
};
```

Same happens on your other activity:

```
//Different activity to the above.
FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
if (user != null) {
    // Using getUid() which stays constant
    mUserId = user.getUid();
}
```

Comment: So the uid stays constant? @Rosario Pereira Fernandes

Comment: Yes it does @TomFinet